# xdebug broken with new ISP

Tags: php, port, xdebug

I had NetBeans/xdebug working great with remote debugging for several weeks ... then changed ISPs (Charter Cable to CenturyLink DSL) and now it doesn't work.  Also, if it matters, I'm using NetBeans on a Mac OS X 10.8 and my webserver is CentOS with WHM/cPanel.

Xdebug is installed correctly on my webserver as phpinfo() shows:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

My php.ini file has the following entries:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug_log
zend_extension = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
```

I've restarted Apached.  I've tried specific IPs with xdebug.remote_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but my ip changes often so I thought the current settings should work too (despite security considerations).

On my Cisco DDR 2200 DSL router I have the following port triggering settings:

```
                    Trigger start/end       Open start / end
netbeans-xdebug TCP 9000    9000        TCP 9000    9000
```

When I choose debug in NetBeans (project or file) my browser comes up properly with:

```
http://myurl/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

and NetBeans just hangs there with:

```
"Waiting for Connection (netbeans-xdebug)" ...
```

and log says this:

```
log opened at 2013-09-14 18:54:56
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-09-14 18:54:56
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Verified that remote address found by "remote_connect_back" matches whatismyip.com.  Is that good?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: FINALLY got it working:

On my Cisco ddr2200 router, had to setup NAT -- Virtual Server.

Server Name: netbeans-xdebug
External Port Start: 9000
External Port End: 9000
Protocol: TCP/UDP
Internal Port Start: 9000
Internal Port End: 9000
Server IP Address: 192.168.64
Remote Host: [left blank]

I think the key was the "Server IP Address" set to the IP of my computer on the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY got it working:

On my Cisco DDR 2200 router, had to setup NAT -- Virtual Server.

Server Name: netbeans-xdebug 
External Port Start: 9000 
External Port End: 9000 
Protocol: TCP/UDP 
Internal Port Start: 9000 
Internal Port End: 9000 
Server IP Address: 192.168.64 
Remote Host: [left blank]

I think the key was the "Server IP Address" set to the IP of my computer on the local network.